# Transpose rows to columns using multiple pivots

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I am trying to transpose rows to columns without any luck . What I have now

| WEEK_NUMBER | VAL9 | VAL4 | VAL5 | VAL7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | 63.27% | 28.58% | 7.92% | 0.23% |
| 52 | 65.66% | 26.16% | 7.80% | 0.38% |
| 50 | 90.97% | 8.45% | 0.29% | 0.29% |
| 46 | 82.49% | 12.43% | 3.01% | 2.06% |
| 47 | 66.33% | 29.53% | 3.77% | 0.36% |
| 51 | 65.36% | 31.83% | 2.69% | 0.11% |
| 49 | 61.88% | 28.29% | 9.46% | 0.37% |
| 44 | 45.34% | 45.55% | 8.45% | 0.66% |
| 48 | 43.75% | 40.01% | 16.01% | 0.23% |

this is based on the following query

```
select 
     to_char(for_date,'ww') as week_number
    ,val9
    ,val4
    ,val5
    ,val7
from data_tab
where to_char(for_date,'yy') = '21'
```

I am trying to get following result

|  | 01 | 02 | .. | 51 | 52 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VAL9 | 0 | 0 | .. | 65.36% | 65.66% |
| VAL4 | 0 | 0 | .. | 31.83% | 26.16% |
| VAL5 | 0 | 0 | .. | 2.69% | 7.80% |
| VAL7 | 0 | 0 | .. | 0.11% | 0.38% |

I have tried by doing next query but with no luck . If someone can just point me in the right direction I would appreciate.

```
select * from (
select 
         to_char(for_date,'ww') as week_number
        ,val9
        ,val4
        ,val5
        ,val7
    from data_tab
    where to_char(for_date,'yy') = '21')
pivot (
    min(val9)--, min(val4), min(val5), min(val7) 
        for week_number in (01 ,02 ,03 ,04 ,05 ,06 ,07 ,08 ,09 ,10 ,11 ,12 ,13 ,14 ,15 ,16 ,17 ,18 ,19 ,20 ,21 ,22 ,23 ,24 ,25 ,26 ,27 ,28 ,29 ,30 ,31 ,32 ,33 ,34 ,35 ,36 ,37 ,38 ,39 ,40 ,41 ,42 ,43 ,44 ,45 ,46 ,47 ,48 ,49 ,50 ,51 ,52 ,53)  
)
```

Comment: You can check out [Dynamic pivot in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-pivot%2boracle?tab=Frequent)

Comment: Thank you @BarbarosÖzhan , I am definitely trying it now .

Comment: Please, describe the issue you have with your current code. "With no luck" is not very descriptive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNPIVOT` and then `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT to_char(for_date,'ww') as week_number
       , val9
       , val4
       , val5
       , val7
  FROM   data_tab
  WHERE  for_date >= DATE '2021-01-01'
  AND    for_date <  DATE '2022-01-01'
  -- WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM for_date) = 2021
)
UNPIVOT (
  value FOR key IN (val9, val4, val5, val7)
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(value) FOR week_number IN (
    '01' AS "01",
    '02' AS "02",
    -- ...
    '44' AS "44",
    '45' AS "45",
    '46' AS "46",
    '47' AS "47",
    '48' AS "48",
    '49' AS "49",
    '50' AS "50",
    '51' AS "51",
    '52' AS "52",
    '53' AS "53"
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_tab (for_date, val9, val4, val5, val7) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-11-13', 63.27, 28.58,  7.92,  0.23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-31', 65.66, 26.16,  7.80,  0.38 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-17', 90.97,  8.45,  0.29,  0.29 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-11-20', 82.49, 12.43,  3.01,  2.06 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-11-27', 66.33, 29.53,  3.77,  0.36 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-24', 65.36, 31.83,  2.69,  0.11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-10', 61.88, 28.29,  9.46,  0.37 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-11-06', 45.34, 45.55,  8.45,  0.66 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-03', 43.75, 40.01, 16.01,  0.23 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | KEY | 01 | 02 | 44 | 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 51 | 52 | 53 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | VAL9 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 45.34 | 63.27 | 82.49 | 66.33 | 43.75 | 61.88 | 90.97 | 65.36 | 65.66 |
> | VAL4 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 45.55 | 28.58 | 12.43 | 29.53 | 40.01 | 28.29 | 8.45 | 31.83 | 26.16 |
> | VAL5 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 8.45 | 7.92 | 3.01 | 3.77 | 16.01 | 9.46 | .29 | 2.69 | 7.8 |
> | VAL7 | *null* | *null* | *null* | .66 | .23 | 2.06 | .36 | .23 | .37 | .29 | .11 | .38 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=16919a2361719a6502cc8546cf7675e4)*

Comment: Thank you very much . I understand what I was missing here !